# Mouse look turns right side towards mouse pointer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, 2d-games, euler-angles

Im trying to get my GameObject to point towards the mouse. It has a child object with a sprite. The childs rotation is set to 0 on all zxis. The sprite points upwards (positive X) at start. The GameObject rotates with the mouse pointer but its always turning its right side towards the mouse pointer. Also when i add force forward it accelerates at the same direction the sprite is pointing which as stated before is not the direction the mouse is. What is my code missing?

```
  var cam = Camera.main;

    // Distance from camera to object.  We need this to get the proper calculation.
    float camDistance = cam.transform.position.y - transform.position.y;

    // Get the mouse position in world space. Using camDis for the Z axis.
    Vector3 mouse = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, camDistance));

    float AngleRad = Mathf.Atan2(mouse.y - transform.position.y, mouse.x - transform.position.x);
    float angle = (180 / Mathf.PI) * AngleRad;

    rb2d.rotation = angle;
```

Comment: Change the angle by 90 degrees

Comment: Are you just making stuff up? What angle?

Comment: Oh! This made it work. 
rb2d.rotation = angle -90;

So should i have done it in another way? I dont understand why i need to remove 90 degrees?

Comment: Because removing 90 degress or adding 90 degrees rotates the shape by 90 degrees, just basic geometry, if something is rotated 90 degrees in the wrong direction rotate it 90 degrees in the other direction to counteract it.

Comment: Yes i meant is this a reasonable way to code if you end up with having to subtract 90 from the result? I get the feeling it should be another way.

Comment: If you were going degrees to radians you could use sin in place of cos or cos in place of sin to shift the rotation but i dont know a better method using tan.

Comment: Oh so its 'tan' that makes it so the -90 degrees is required?

Comment: Yes, but tan is the only option here as far as I'm aware, so I'd just do it with the fix that you applied.

Comment: Thanks! Do you wnat to make an answer out of it so i can mark it as resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shape is rotated by 90 degrees due to the way that your calculations resolve the angle, you can account for this by using:

```
rb2.rotation = angle - 90;
```